# sessionScope Variable Being Lost

Tags: xpages, session-scope

I am checking a sessionScope variable in an XPage in beforePageLoad, and if it is null, setting it to a random value.

For some reason it often is equal to null, and so I keep losing the variable, even as quickly as 5 minutes even though I have the Session Timeout in the database set to 90 minutes.

I have tried the ExtLib KeepSessionAlive, set to as little as 180 seconds, no luck. I also tried the code here:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=keeping-your-xpage-session-alive-%E2%80%93-without-keepsessionalive

This also does not seem to work. This is a test server so not under any load. I have always found sessionScope variables pretty reliable up to now. What am I doing wrong?

```
var cartID = sessionScope.cartID; 

if (cartID == null) { 
    sessionScope.cartID = @Unique(); 
}
```

Comment: Show me your code.  Here is a wild guess: by chance are you checking using a single equals in your if statement.  if(yourValue = null){ then reset variable}.  This would not give you an error, but would assign the value to null.  You want the double equals to check if it is null.  I have done this before.

Comment: Using the single equals instead of double equals could occur anywhere you reference the sessionScope variable.  It is very easy to overlook.  Do a search on the name and check each reference.

Comment: Code added. The code works quite well most of the time. Only occasionally the variable is reset, either after some time has elapsed, or when switching pages.

Comment: Is there another place in the code that also sets the sessionScope.cartID to something else?  Search for "cartID ="  to check.

Comment: I've actually done a test with 2 pages, with nothing on them except the same code as above, and a link to switch between pages. The same thing happens, so I think it is either a server problem or a bug. Now I have no idea what to do...

Comment: John, Not likely a bug. In your XSP Properties, on the Persistence Tab, did you change anything there. The default is what you want. Also, please tell some more what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe this will help is in suggesting alternatives.

Comment: I changed the default Session Timeout in the db as I said in my post, from blank to 90 minutes. I lose the sessionScope variable in as little as 5 minutes. I have switched to using a cookie, although I am more interested in why sessionScope is not working properly.

Comment: Did you change the Persistence in the XSP Properties?  If you don't have the XPages toolbar from openNTF then I would advise getting it. It allows you to see your scoped variables easily.  Then try navigating around your application, and try to see what action causes the sessionScope variable to reset.

Comment: I don't remember, I don't think I changed it. It is currently set to: Server Persistence mode: "Keep Pages on Disk" and Page Persistence Mode: server default. I am afraid the XPages Toolbar will communicate with the server and maybe change the interaction with the sessionScope. This does not reflect a production scenario so it would not give a good test.

Comment: I will show what I mean in an answer. I am not sure this is your "answer", but I can't put images in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

John,

Please make sure that you persist changes between requests, in your XSP Properties.

[image]

---

Also, John in reply to your comment:  The debug toolbar is not going to communicate with the server for you. It just reports the actions that are taking place with your UI.  It is an invaluable tool for me in tracking issues like you are having.

Comment: Yes, I had 'Persist sessions' set already. The only difference was Session Timeout was changed to 90

Comment: Good, I needed to be sure, but I am running out of suggestions. I let you know if I think of anything.

Comment: Hi John, did u found any solution for this? We are also experiencing the same issue.